# Second Call to NetworkStream BeginRead() Massive Resource Contention

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, tcpclient, networkstream

I am coding a server/client project with `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream` objects.  I expect many clients to connect to the server, which are stored in a `List<>` of custom `NetworkNode` objects, each of which has a `TcpClient` and a `NetworkStream` for communication with the respective client.

The server needs to be able to maintain a connection to the client and wait for and action messages immediately (quickly) as received. Synchronous polling is very undesirable for this application, nor do I have any desire to code it that way.

Currently the server is asynchronously accepting clients and adding them to the `List<>`, which is working quite smoothly.  I have tested this with a console app generating up to 100 clients and connecting to the server at the loopback address within a very short period of time (< 1sec).

When a client is added to the `List<>` the object uses the `GetStream()` method to return the client's `NetworkStream` object.  I am attempting to use the `NetworkStream.BeginRead()` method to implement async data reception from each TCP client.  The first call to the method is as:

```
this.Stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, readBufferOffset, readBuffer.Length - readBufferOffset, 
    new AsyncCallback(nodeStreamReadCallback), this.Stream);
```

Because the console test application sends some data as soon as it connects to the server, the object's `readCallback(IAsyncResult)` method is called almost immediately:

```
private void readCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    NetworkStream _stream = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;

    int _bytesRead = 0;

    _bytesRead = _stream.EndRead(ar);

    this.Stream.Write(readBuffer, readBufferOffset, _bytesRead);

    //increase buffer offset value
    readBufferOffset += _bytesRead;

    //TODO process the received data
    ...

    //wait for the next chunk of data
    this.Stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, readBufferOffset, readBuffer.Length - readBufferOffset, 
    new AsyncCallback(readCallback), this.Stream);
}
```

I am performing a second call to `Stream.BeginRead()` with the intention of waiting for the next block of data to arrive or become available, whenever in the future that might be.

When I comment out the second call to `Stream.BeginRead()` everything operates very smoothly.  All the data is received and sent back to every client, without delay and with extremely minimal thread use (avg 2 to 3 additional threads during the process).

However - even if only a **single client** has connected, if I attempt to make a **second call** to `Stream.BeginRead()` within the `readCallback()` method (as above) I encounter **massive** contention issues.  For a single client, CPU usage after the second call jumps from ~ 0% to between 30% and 60%, and the number of threads can jump from 11 to as many as 35.

So it's a threading or recursion issue, and I feel I should be waiting for something when I'm not however I can't quite wrap my head around what's going on here. This is the same pattern I've used with the `TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient()` so I think it must operate differently.

I appreciate any and all advice that you might have to offer, and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you check your `_bytesRead` for being 0?  Because that means your stream was closed on the remote side. Calling `BeginRead` on such a stream again would result directly in calling your callback with a count of read bytes of 0 again and again.

Comment: where do you reset the `readBufferOffset`?

Comment: @abto You're right!  In my console test application I was sending data through a `using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(){}` block.  When the using block finished sending data, the stream was no longer available, and returned 0 in the `_bytesRead` parameter.  Checking for this prevented the infinite loop.  Thank you!  Really this is the answer, would you please move it into an Answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `_bytesRead` for 0, because that means your stream was closed on the remote side. Calling `BeginRead` on such a stream again would result directly in calling your callback with a count of read bytes of 0 again and again.

Comment: You're right! In my console test application I was sending data through a `using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(){}` block. When the using block finished sending data, the stream was no longer available, and returned 0 in the `_bytesRead` parameter. Checking for this prevented the loop.